# When merged some of the files from source branch do not show in destination branch?

Tags: git, merge, egit

I have a branch `fix` derived from the `master`. I have made some changes to `fix` branch committed those & pushed. Now I want the changes of `fix` in `master` but it behaves weird :

1] I have all changes committed & pushed for the `fix`,
2] I switch to `master` then merge changes from the `fix`,
3] I do get merge conflict which I resolved those & make the local commit,
4] There are few files originally on branch `fix`, which do not show up in `master` after merge,
5] But the same file shows when I compare the master branch with fix,

I am using Eclipse IDE egit.

What are the possible reasons that may lead to the above situation?

Note: Prior to merging I make sure both the branches are updated with origin.
I expect all the files from `fix` to be shown in `master` after the merge

Comment: Did you your someone from your team accidentally/intentionally delete one of those files on master prior to merge?

Comment: @22Kar No one is deleting anything, I am trying to merge locally first then will push to remote file is intact on the branch "fix", I am really surprised with this behaviour which happened the first time

Comment: Something doesn't add up. Either files were skipped during merge, or were not added to the commit. Could you post exact set of commands you've tried with merging?

Comment: Have any of your colleagues renamed any of those files at the same time as changing the contents? This can cause git to recognise the operation as a delete and create as opposed to a simple rename.

Comment: Too many things could go wrong, your explanation is not detailed enough to reproduce your problem. To make this a good question, use git command line tools and show the output here.